# Where to place Identity data and settings in ASP.NET MVC 3-tier architecture application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, identity, n-layer

I am working with ASP.NET MVC app and trying to move it to 3-layer architecture. I can't figure out where to place Identity data, in which layer? Should I make two DB contexts (within two layers) or make reference from Presentation Layer to DAL? Some people say that there shouldn't be reference between PL and DAL. Some hints, please?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are storing user details, passwords and settings in the data layer. But the data layer only needs to know what the table structure is and how to access it. The business layer needs to know how to encrypt/decrypt the password and what user information is available. This would then send that information in the form of data transfer objects to the presentation layer. The presentation layer only needs to pass user and password in whatever format to the business layer and may need to know limited information about the user supplied by the business layer. The presentation layer should not need to know the structure of the tables or how the data access layer reads that data and the data layer doesn't need to know what the data it has access to actually means. The business layer should know most about how the system functions as a whole, but it should not care how the data is actually read and written in the data layer, nor how information is displayed and accepted in the presentation layer.

Waffled on a bit, but I think that makes at least some sense.